# express app and route that accepts csv and writes to a file

Tags: node.js, express, csv, https

I need to write an API route using Express and NodeJS that accepts a CSV in the body of the POST and writes it to a file locally. Here is the basis of the code i have so far:

In server.js

```
import https from 'https';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import apiRoutes from './server/routes/apiRoutes.js';


    
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 443;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

In apiRoutes.js:

```
import express from 'express';

import scriptsUtilities from './v1Utils/scriptsUtilities.js';


const router = express.Router();

// /api/v1

router.use('/v1/scripts', scriptsUtilities);



export default router;
```

In scriptsUtilities.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import fs from 'fs';      
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/upload')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log('touched upload get');
      res.json({data: []});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('upload get error', error);
      res.json({message: 'error in upload'});
    }
  });

export default router;
```

In scriptsUtilities.js is where I need the express route that will accept a csv and write it to a file.

Comment: What do you mean with "writes it to a file"? Are you talking just a literal byte dump? Also, if you're dealing with CSV data, why are you using `res.json()`, which is specifically for converting a JSON payload to native JS object data? For CSV you'd want `res.text()`, you're dealing with plain text, not JSON strings.

Comment: Take a look at [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). It should put you on the right track for uploading files over http.